# Find index position where the value of data between 2 arrays has changed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two arrays

```
initial:["David","Brad"]
after:["David","Cristina"]
```

So between above two arrays Value at position 2 has been changed, so how can I simply return the index position of change:

Desired Result: [2]

In case both values are changed the desired result would be [1,2]

I tried below,

```
 var res= a.after.filter( function( p, index) {
                return Object.keys(p).some( function( prop ) {
                  return p[prop] !== a.initial[index][prop];
                })
              })
```

The above code returns output as ["Cristina"] which is the changed value in after array.

How can this be tweaked to get the index position instead of value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two arrays and then return the index of the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113362/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-then-return-the-index-of-the-difference)

Comment: Thanks,for the reference, not exactly that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both arrays always same size? Can the elements of the array be objects? Because you are comparing object keys...

From your example and without more definition on the problem I think you can achieve it like this

```
var res = a.after.reduce( (acc, item, index) => {
    if(index >= a.initial.length || item !== a.initial[index]){
         acc.push(index+1);   
    }
    return acc;
},  []);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the array's elements are strings/numbers and the arrays are of same length, the below code should do the work

Please verify..

```js
initial = ["David","Brad"];
after = ["David","Cristina"];
arr = [];
  
this.initial.map((i,v)=> {
   if (i !== this.after[v]) {
     this.arr.push(v+1)
    }
});
  
  console.log(this.arr)
```